# 400 (Bad Request) when sending a post request from React to Django

Tags: reactjs, redux, django-rest-framework, react-redux, axios

I'm trying to use react and redux to create a simple login page. When I click on the login button I get the error `400(Bad Request)` from both
frontend  and backend. I'm using simplejwt authentication.

```
I have the following as part of the redux action (auth.jsx)

export const login = (email, password) => async dispatch => {
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
        }
    };
    const body = JSON.stringify({email, password});
    try{
        const res = await axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/user/login`, body, config)

        dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
            payload: res.data
        })
        dispatch(load_user());
    }   catch (err){
        dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_FAIL,
    
        })
    }
        console.log('You hit the wrong url')
}
```

Redux DevTools displays the catch in the try and catch block``type(pin):"LOGIN_FAIL"`

```
Login.jsx

const Login = ({ login }) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
      email: '',
      password: ''

  });

  const {email, password} = formData;
  

  const onChange = e => setFormData ({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value});
  const onSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        login(email, password);
  }
  return(
      <div className='container'>
          <Form onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)}>
                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicEmail">
                    <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="example@email.com" onChange={e => onChange(e)} required />
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicPassword">
                    <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="Password" minLength='6' onChange={e => onChange(e)} required />
                </Form.Group>
                <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                    Login
                </Button>
                
        </Form>
      </div>
  )
//  const mapStateToProps = state => ({

//  })
}

export default connect(null, {login}) (Login)
```

The login backend API can be seen  from `await axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/user/login`part of the code where`
REACT_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:8000`. The problem now is that when I send a post request by clicking on the submit button to login a user, the content of the form` email and password`does is not passed along because the error on both frontend and backend is`POST http://localhost:8000/user/login 400 (Bad Request)`
How do I fix this or, rather, what am I getting wrong?

Comment: Since you are using axios, you should not need to stringfy it to a body. You can send `{ email, password }` directly

Comment: Thanks @LBald. Even without stringifying the error is the same

Comment: could you post the backend logs from django? Assuming you are on the dev server the cause should be clearly shown in the console where you ran the django server.

Comment: Sure. In django console what is being displayed when I click on login is `Bad Request: /user/login
[09/Nov/2021 02:42:25] "POST /user/login HTTP/1.1" 400 86`

Comment: Seems most likely to be related with the request body structure. Is the login a customized view? If so could you please post the target django view as well?

Comment: Thank you @Archvec. I opened another question on this. I'm able to authenticate now but the user remains null. I also included the login view.py in the newly open question. Please find it in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69896381/%c3%97-unhandled-rejection-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading

Answer (score 0):

The Login Url is wrong It should be **http://localhost:8000/rest-auth/login/** to use a token based auth. You need rest framework.