# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'access')

Tags: reactjs, django, redux, react-redux

[image]
I'm using react and redux to create simple user authentication. When I click on the login button the user get's authenticated, yet
the user remails null. Through debugging, I have come to realize that the error is from the the auth action. From the auth action function (found in the code below) with the variable name`load_user` I do not understand the right URL to use. I understand that it's supposed to take a get request, but the login API I'm using cannot take a get request. By using GET request there I get `method not allowed`. It's the data obtained from this `load_user` that is dispatched in payload which is used to assess the ACCESS and REFRESH tokens in redux reducer. Because I'm not making the correct axios request react is unable to read the property of the access token that's been returned, hence I'm getting the named error.

```
Auth Action
_____________
import axios from 'axios';
import { LOGIN_SUCCESS, LOGIN_FAIL, USER_LOADED_SUCCESS, USER_LOADED_FAIL,} from './types';


export const load_user = () => async dispatch =>{
    if(localStorage.getItem('access')){
        const config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type':'application/json',
                'Authorization': `JWT ${localStorage.getItem('access')}`,
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
        };
        try{
        const res = await axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/account/login`, config)

        dispatch({
            type: USER_LOADED_SUCCESS,
            payload: res.data
        })
        
    }
        catch (err){
            dispatch({
                type: USER_LOADED_FAIL,
            })
        }
    }else {
        dispatch({
            type: USER_LOADED_FAIL,
        })
    }
    
};

export const login = (email, password) => async dispatch => {
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
        }
    };
    //const body = JSON.stringify({email, password});
    const body = {email, password};
    const data = JSON.stringify(body);
    
    try{
        console.log(data)
        const res = await axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/account/login`, data, config)

        dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
            payload: res.data
        })
        dispatch(load_user());
    }   catch (err){
        dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_FAIL,
    
        })
    }
    
}
```

Auth Reducer

```
import { LOGIN_SUCCESS, LOGIN_FAIL, USER_LOADED_SUCCESS, USER_LOADED_FAIL,} from '../actions/types'

const initialState = {
    access: localStorage.getItem('access'),
    refresh: localStorage.getItem('refresh'),
    isAuthenticated: null,
    user: null
};

const authReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    const { type, payload } = action;
    switch (type) {
        case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
            localStorage.setItem('access', payload.access);
            return{
                ...state,
                isAuthenticated: true,
                access: payload.access,
                refresh: payload.refresh
            }
        case USER_LOADED_SUCCESS:
            localStorage.setItem('access', payload.access);
            return{
                ...state,
                user: payload
          
            }
          case USER_LOADED_FAIL:
            localStorage.setItem('access', payload.access);
            return{
                ...state,
                user: null
          
            }
        case LOGIN_FAIL:
            localStorage.removeItem('access');
            localStorage.removeItem('refresh');
            return {
                ...state,
                isAuthenticated: false,
                access: null,
                refresh: null,
                user: null
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default authReducer
```

When ever I login the user, I get the following output from the django server console (NOTE that both status 200 and status 400 appear
on the console follow a single login)

```
[09/Nov/2021 10:05:28] "POST /account/login HTTP/1.1" 200 506
Bad Request: /user/login
[09/Nov/2021 10:05:28] "POST /account/login HTTP/1.1" 400 76
```

Login views.py

```
class LoginAPIView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Please, my question is, how do I know the approximate url to send axios request since the login API cannot accept a get request?

Comment: I suggest you to be more focus on the backend in the question. You have a `400` error code, may be the client ip address is not in the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` or something else. Show your view too

Comment: Thanks @ Rvector. The ALLOWED_HOST is  set to an empty array, [ ]. I also added the login views.py at the end of the question above

Comment: Set `ALLOWED_HOSTS` to `localhost:3000` default react address or change if needed. And try the same request

Comment: Instead of write a custom authentication views, [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65158850/how-to-create-custom-login-view-with-django-rest-auth) ; you can use [Django rest auth](https://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to DRY.

Comment: When I authenticate with the API on Thunder Client or Postman I don't get that error. And from the Redux DevTools, the users details, including access and refresh tokens are being returned to the Frontend. The issue I'm having is that the programme is not capturing the access token that is being returned